# How can I return an AngularJS promise from a simple function?

Tags: angularjs

My code is doing this:

```
wordFormRowClicked = (wf): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    if (this.wordFormIdentity != wf.wordFormIdentity) {
        return self.wordFormUpdate(wf).then(() => {
            this.wordFormIdentity = wf.wordFormIdentity;
        })
    }
}
```

self.wordFormUpdate returns a promise but when the `if` condition does not match then no promise is returned.

How can I return a promise in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming wordFormUpdate is promise:

```
wordFormRowClicked = (wf): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    if (this.wordFormIdentity != wf.wordFormIdentity) {
        return self.wordFormUpdate(wf);
    }
}
```

You can run your function as:

```
wordFormRowClicked(someParam).then(() => {
    this.wordFormIdentity = wf.wordFormIdentity;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a promise and return it at the end of the function

```
if (...) { 
    return ...
}
return new Promise(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. What would be inside the (...) I just want to return a promise to show that the operation has completed.

Comment: @SamanthaJ — A function that immediately resolves the Promise I assume.